# Using MySQL database from Artifactory plugin

Tags: mysql, groovy, artifactory

I'm trying to write a monitoring plugin for Artifactory using MySQL. The idea is that the plugin will collect some data using the Artifactory public API and some command line utilities, then write that data to a MySQL database to be analysed later. The problem is that the plugin can't find the jdbc driver. I placed the driver JAR in `<artifactory-home>/etc/plugins/lib` and I'm registering it like so:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/artifactoryTest', <user>, <pass>, 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```

This results in a ClassNotFoundException on com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. It seems the class loader used by Artifactory can't find the JAR.

Is there a way to make this work or am I barking up the wrong tree? I'm aware there may be some database technologies that would be better suited for this purpose but many seem like overkill for such a basic use case and I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Looks like it would work if you put the jar in WEB-INF/lib inside artifactory.war. From https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins "Scripts have access to the full classpath of Artifactory" However, whether that is permissible by Arifactory EULA and/or from an Artifactory upgrade viewpoint is something that should be considered.

Comment: @Pradyumna Thanks, looks like that is my best bet just now. I came across this similar issue which is marked as "will not implement" so doesn't seem like this will change any time soon: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed possible. Artifactory can be configured to use a number of different databases, including MySQL, so I figured there must be a way to use the same driver that Artifactory uses and indeed there is.

In the [documentation for setting up Artifactory with MySQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MySQL) it says:

> Download the MySQL JDBC driver (available from the  MySQL website) 
>   and copy the mysql-connector-java-.jar file into the server's
>   shared lib directory.  For example $TOMCAT_HOME/lib when installed as
>   a service or $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/lib in the standalone version.

Simply dropping the JDBC driver JAR in the shared lib directory makes it available for use within plugins. I imagine this approach would work for any other JARs too.